# Angular UI Router - Resolves with Child and Parents

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a angular page, and depending if a value in the Page object equals a particular value, i would like to maybe load another state, i say maybe, because if it is not then i have no need to load another view (but maybe this is where this is going wrong?)

Here is my current state configuration

```
$stateProvider
    .state('app', {
        url: '',
        abstract: true,
        templateProvider: ['$templateCache', function ($templateCache) {
            return $templateCache.get('app/main/main.html');
        }],
        controller: 'MainController',
        resolve: {
            Pages: ['PageApi', function (PageApi) {
                return PageApi.getAll();
            }]
        }

    })
    .state('app.page', {
        url: '/page/{id}',
        params: {
            id: { value: 0 }
        },
        templateProvider: ['$templateCache', function ($templateCache) {
            return $templateCache.get('app/page/page.html');
        }],
        controller: 'PageController',
        resolve: {
            Page: ['$stateParams', 'PageApi', function ($stateParams, PageApi) {
                return PageApi.get($stateParams.id);
            }],
            Contents: ['$stateParams', 'ContentApi', function($stateParams, ContentApi) {
                return ContentApi.getByPage($stateParams.id);
            }]
        }
    })
    .state('app.page.search', {
        templateProvider: ['$templateCache', function ($templateCache) {
            return $templateCache.get('app/page/partials/page-search.tpl.html');
        }],
        controller: 'PageSearchController',
        resolve: {
            Module: ['ModuleApi', 'Page', function(ModuleApi, Page) {
                return ModuleApi.get(Page.moduleId);
            }]
        }
    })
```

As you can see i have my base state called app, which loads my basic page (all fine).

I also have app.page which will load my partial page.html (again fine)

app.page uses this controller and this partial html file.

```
angular.module('app').controller('PageController', ['$state', '$scope', 'Page', 'Contents', 
    function ($state, $scope, Page, Contents) {

        if (Page.action == 'search')
            $state.go('app.page.search');
    }]);
```

app/page/page.html

```
<!-- main -->
<section role="main" class="row">
    <div ui-view></div>

    <div ng-if="showSide" class="col-md-3">
        <div page-location location="side"></div>
    </div>
</section>
```

app/main/main.html

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <!-- content -->
        <div ui-view class="content"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now i thought that child states had the same resolves as their parent, but when the app.page.search resolve executes, it throws an error saying Page is undefined.

How can i access app.Page resolves from app.page.search?

I have obviously set something up incorrectly but not sure what.

As i said before, app should load my basic page (which it does), app.page should load my page contents, and app.page.search should load more content depending on the Page object loaded in the app.Page resolve.  Maybe i should not be changing the state in the pageController? But i do not know if you can change state from within another state config?

Answer (score 0):

I'm actually pretty sure that what you wan't isn't a nested view. Anyway here is two solutions for you :

First one :

You actually can scope your variable in your PageController.

```
$scope.Page = Page;
```

In your PageSearchController, you'll be able to access it with :

```
$scope.Page;
```

You have to know the mechanics of angularJS $scope.

If you request a var from $scope. It'll search in the current scope if this variable exists. If it don't it'll search in the parent scope (here your parent state controller) if the var exists. If it reach the rootScope and don't find your var, it fire an exception.

Second solution :

You probably want to load a part of your HTML depending on some information. Then don't use states, just use ng-include with a ng-if condition.

```
<ng-include ng-if="Page.action == 'search'" ng-controller="PageSearchController" src="app/page/partials/page-search.tpl.html"></ng-include>
```

If this is really a nested view, choose the first one. If this is just a part of your view, choose the second one.

Hope it'll help you solving your issue.

Comment: If using nginclude is there anyway to stop the second loading until some promises have been resolved like u can with states?

Comment: Actually no. In my knowledge i dont know a way to do a resolve With an ng-include. Maybe the first one Is your usecase.